# Explaining why relative homology group is considered as quotient group but not subgroup?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

**Notation (following Hatcher's Algebraic Topology):**

(1) $\Delta^n$ is the standard $n$-simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n$ i.e. the smallest convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ containing $0$ and standard unit vectors and give it a subspace topology.

(2) For topological space $X$, let $C_n(X)$ denote the free abelian group on all continuous functions $\sigma:\Delta^n\rightarrow X$.

(3)For a subspace $A$ of $X$, let $C_n(X,A)$ denote the quotient $C_n(x)/C_n(A)$.

With this notation, Hatcher says (p.115)

> The quotient $C_n(X)/C_n(A)$ could also be viewed as a subgroup of $C_n(X)$, subgroup with basis the singular $n$-simplices $\sigma:\Delta^n\rightarrow X$ whose image is not contained in $A$. *However, the boundary map does not take this subgroup of $C_n(X)$ to the corresponding subgroup of $C_{n-1}(X)$*, so it is usually better to regard $C_n(X,A)$ as a quotient rather than a subgroup of $C_n(X)$.

**Question.** Can one give a simple example to justify the *italic* statement in the above quote? I was unable to construct it, although it could be simple.

Comment: Consider any interval with one endpoint in A and one endpoint not contained in A.

Comment: Let $X$ be the $2$-simplex and let $A$ be one of the standard embeddings of the $1$ simplex in $X$. Now take $\Delta^2 \to X$ to be the identity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X=[0,1]$ and $A=\{0\}\subset X$.  Consider a singular simplex $\sigma:\Delta^1\to [0,1]$ which is a path from $0$ to $1$.  Then the image of $\sigma$ is not contained in $A$, so $\sigma$ would be in the subgroup generated by simplices not contained in $A$.  On the other hand, $\partial\sigma$ is the difference of two singular simplices (the $0$-simplex with image $1$ and the $0$-simplex with image $0$), one not contained in $A$ and one contained in $A$.  So $\partial\sigma$ would not be in the subgroup generated by simplices not contained in $A$.

More generally, a simplex $\sigma$ whose image is not contained in $A$ might have boundary faces that are contained in $A$.  Unless those boundary faces happen to all cancel each other out when you add up $\partial \sigma$, then, $\partial\sigma$ will not be a linear combination of simplices whose images are not contained in $A$.